# UnityWebRequest is not completed after selecting a file from Open File Panel in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

```
string path;
AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
```

---

```
path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Audio Files", "", "wav");
if (path != null)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip("file:///" + path, AudioType.WAV))
        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
    {
        Debug.LogError(www.error);
    }
    else
        {
        //Debug.Log(www.url);
        audio.clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
        audio.Play();
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        }
}
```

after executing this block of code, on Play mode, A file picker runs successfully, however after selecting an audio file, the console throws the InvalidOperationException: Cannot get content from an unfinished UnityWebRequest object
which caused by this line

```
audio.clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
```

my assumption is that I somehow missing a step in between getting the audio file path from the file picker and stream the actual audio clip using the path.

Debug.Log(www.url) will successfully print the file URI scheme.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Comment: @derHugo Hello! could you give me a hand with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75491463/cannot-get-content-from-an-unfinished-unitywebrequest-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general watch out with your `using` .. you should wrap it in `{ }` for readability and for preventing unexpected behavior

Then for some reason you do

```
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

**after** trying to access the results .... this line should be the first after the `using` line .. before trying to check whether the request was sent correctly and trying to access the download content

```
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip("file:///" + path, AudioType.WAV))
{
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
    {
        Debug.LogError(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        audio.clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
        audio.Play();           
    }
}
```